# Oracle JDBC XMLType NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sqlxml, xmltype

When I try to pass SQLXML object to Oracle stored procedure via JDBC in a Java 6 application running on Weblogic, I am getting the following error:

> ```
> Cause: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError 
> Location: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xdb/XMLType 
>  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xdb/XMLType
>        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createSQLXML(PhysicalConnection.java:9724)
>        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.createSQLXML(Connection.java:1034)
> ```

The relevant part of code:

```
    String sql = "{call " + procedureName + "(?)}";
    CallableStatement callableStatement = mOracleConnection.prepareCall(sql);
    SQLXML sqlxml = mOracleConnection.createSQLXML();
    DOMResult dr = new DOMResult();
    sqlxml.setResult(DOMResult.class);
    dr.setNode(parameter);
    callableStatement.setSQLXML(1, sqlxml);
    callableStatement.executeUpdate();
    callableStatement.close();
```

[This article](http://thinktibits.blogspot.com/2014/08/oracle-xmltype-java-sql-sqlxml-example.html) attributes the error to the missing xdb.jar.

I downloaded **xdb6.jar** from [Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html) and seemingly added it to CLASSPATH.

I also double-checked that `oracle.xdb.XMLtype` class file is present in the JAR.

I am still getting this error.

Any suggestions on further troubleshooting?

**EDIT** [11/19/15]:

I added `Class.forName("oracle.xdb.XMLType")` to test the explicit loading of the "missing" class. After adding **xmlparserv2.jar** into the mix, my test code worked fine, but I got the same exception in `PhysicalConnection`.

I am using a pooled connection, if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that oracle/xdb/XMLType is part of xdb.jar, you should ensure that this jar is part of your CLASSPATH or ensure that it is part of your WAR file.

In order to understand how the classloading is working and why it can not find your class, you could start your WLS instance with these debug flags:

```
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.Verbose=true 
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.Verbose=true 
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.ClasspathClassFinder=true 
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.DefaultFilteringClassLoader.Verbose=true 
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.Verbose=true 
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.ResourceDump=true 
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.URLClassFinder.Verbose=true 
-Dweblogic.log.StdoutSeverity=Debug 
-Dweblogic.log.RedirectStdoutToServerLogEnabled=true 
-Dweblogic.log.RedirectStderrToServerLogEnabled=true
```